# How to edit the metadata information of an object in cloud storage bucket using golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage, metadatatype

I've tried to insert a csv file from a local machine to the cloud storage bucket but it is storing as a text file. When i tried including Metadata option in

object := &storage.Object{Name: objectName, Metadata: map[string]string{"Content-Type": "text/csv; charset=utf-8"}}

It is creating another slot Content-Type and Storing the data but not changing the default value. Tried most of the options from google but unable to resolve this issue. Following is the code snippet.

```
package main

import (
        "flag"
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "golang.org/x/net/context"
        "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
        storage "google.golang.org/api/storage/v1"
)

const (
        // This can be changed to any valid object name.
        objectName = "result"
        // This scope allows the application full control over resources in Google Cloud Storage
        scope = storage.DevstorageFullControlScope
)

var (
        projectID  = flag.String("project", "phani-1247 ", "Your cloud project ID.")
        bucketName = flag.String("bucket", "test-csvstorage", "The name of an existing bucket within your project.")
        fileName   = flag.String("file", "/home/phanikumar_dytha0/src/phani-1247/master/router/result.csv", "The file to upload.")
)



func main() {
        flag.Parse()
       client, err := google.DefaultClient(context.Background(), scope)
        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Printf("error")
        }
        // Insert an object into a bucket.
        object := &storage.Object{Name: objectName, Metadata: map[string]string{"Content-Type": "text/csv; charset=utf-8"}}
        file, err := os.Open(*fileName)
        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Printf("error")
        }
        service, err := storage.New(client)
        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Printf("error")
        }

        if res, err := service.Objects.Insert(*bucketName, object).Media(file).Do(); err == nil {
                //fmt.Printf("%v",res,"\n")
                fmt.Printf("Created object %v at location %v\n\n", res.Name, res.SelfLink)
        } else {
                fmt.Printf("Objects.Insert failed: %v", err)
        }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacted Google Tech support. They gave the following answer and it worked perfectly.

> I found the root cause that explained why the Content-type set via CS
>   API is "text/plain; charset=utf-8" instead of "text/csv;
>   charset=utf-8".
>
> As desribed on the [CLI-Go reference](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/storage/v1#ObjectsInsertCall.Media) the function Media(): the
>   Content-Type header used in the upload request will be determined by
>   sniffing the contents of r, unless a MediaOption generated by
>   googleapi.ContentType is supplied.
>
> So to generate a MediaOption you need to call to [googleapi.ContentType](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/googleapi#ContentType):
>
> I modified your script by importing "google.golang.org/api/googleapi"
>   and calling insert as follows:
>
> ```
> service.Objects.Insert(*bucketName,
> object).Media(file,googleapi.ContentType("text/csv;
> charset=utf-8")).Do();
> ```
>
> It seems that Media() overrides the data set on Object.

Answer (score 1):

`Metadata` is a string -> string map of custom, user-defined object properties. What you're looking for is `ContentType`.

```
object := &storage.Object{Name: objectName, ContentType: "text/csv; charset=utf-8"}
```

Comment: Hi Brandon I've tried that one too but it is not working, the type of the file is still text/plain when i upload the file in bucket through the code.